# Dictionary in python for implementing the 37% Rule

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib

I am trying the famous 37% rule from the book- "Algorithms to live by" by Brian Christian.

The 37% Rule basically says that when you need to screen a range of options in a limited amount of time - be they candidates for a job, new apartments, or potential romantic partners - the best time to make a decision is when you've looked at 37% of those options.

At that point in a selection process, you'll have gathered enough information to make an informed decision, but you won't have wasted too much time looking at more options than necessary. At the 37% mark, you're in a good place to pick the best of the bunch.

A common thought experiment to demonstrate this theory - developed by non-PC math guys in the 1960s - is called "The Secretary Problem."

The program is running but I wanted to start to consider selecting the candidates after 37% of the candidates. Since I am using dictionary, I do not get to access the elements after a specified number of candidates. How can I make this possible?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# for visualising scores
def initiate(candidates):
print("Total candidates are : ",len(candidates))
lookup_num=int(len(candidates) *0.37)
#finds 37% of the candidates
average=lookup(candidates)
# returns average of lookup phase
chosen=select_cad(candidates,lookup_num,average)
# selects a candidate based on lookUp average
print("The chosen candidate is : {} ".format(chosen))

def lookup(candidates):
    average_score=0
    for cands,score in candidates.items():
        average_score+=score
    average_score=int(average_score/len(candidates))
    print("The average score in lookup is : ",average_score)
    #return the average score to average local variable
    return average_score



def select_cad(candidates,lookup_num,average):
    for cands,score in candidates.items():
        if(score>average):
            return cands
        else:
            continue
        print("Something went wrong!")
        quit


candidates={"Husain":85, "Chirag":94 ,"Asim":70,"Ankit":65 ,"Saiteja":65 ,"Absar":75 ,"Premraj":70 ,"Sagar":75 ,"Himani":75 ,"Parth":76 ,"Sumedha":70 ,"Revati":65 ,"Sageer":65 ,"Noorjahan":60 ,"Muzammil":65 ,"Shifa":56 , "Dipti":65 , "Dheeraj":70 }
initiate(candidates)

plt.bar(range(len(candidates)), list(candidates.values()), align='center', color='green')
plt.xticks(range(len(candidates)), list(candidates.keys()))
plt.show()
```

How can I make it more flexible to update the average score even in selection phase?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the "37% Rule" and what you're trying to accomplish?  People may be able to help you, but you're making a lofty assumption others are familiar with the book and this specific rule.

Comment: You might wanna consider using ordered dictionaries using `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: From what I'm picking up from your description it looks like you have an error in your `lookup` function.  You supply `lookup_num` as a parameter, but never use it in the function?  Was this an oversight or do you only want to return `lookup_num` number of candidates from your `candidates` dictionary?

Comment: You were right. Lookup_num was irrelevant in lookup(). As I changed this code a few times before uploading so I may have missed this. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I've posted the code below and put lookup_num to good use. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've updated my previous code with a few variables and used lookup_num for iterating. Still using the unordered dictionary and it works like a charm. Check it out.**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# for visualising scores
def initiate(candidates):
print("Total candidates are : ",len(candidates))
lookup_num=int(len(candidates) *0.37)
#finds 37% of the candidates
average, lookup_candidates=lookup(candidates,lookup_num)
# returns average of lookup phase
chosen=select_cad(candidates,lookup_num,average,lookup_candidates)
# selects a candidate based on lookUp average
print("The chosen candidate is : {} ".format(chosen))

def lookup(candidates,lookup_num):
    average_score=0
    count=0
    lookup_candidates=[]
    for cands,score in candidates.items():
        if(not count>=lookup_num):
            lookup_candidates.append(cands)
            average_score+=score
            count+=1
    average_score=int(average_score/count)
    print("Look Up candidates are : ",lookup_candidates)

    print("The average score in lookup is : ",average_score)
    #return the average score to average local variable
    return average_score,lookup_candidates



def select_cad(candidates,lookup_num,average,lookup_candidates):
    for cands,score in candidates.items():
        if(score>average and cands not in lookup_candidates):
        #because 37% rule does not allows us to go back to select a candidate from the lookup phase
            return cands
            #return selected candidate to chosen variable
        else:
            continue
        print("Something went wrong!")
        quit


candidates={"Husain":85, "Chirag":94 ,"Asim":70,"Ankit":65 ,"Saiteja":65 ,"Absar":75 ,"Premraj":70 ,"Sagar":75 ,"Himani":75 ,"Parth":76 ,"Sumedha":70 ,"Revati":65 ,"Sageer":65 ,"Noorjahan":60 ,"Muzammil":65 ,"Shifa":56 , "Dipti":65 , "Dheeraj":70 }
initiate(candidates)

plt.bar(range(len(candidates)), list(candidates.values()), align='center', color='green')
plt.xticks(range(len(candidates)), list(candidates.keys()))
plt.xlabel("Candidates")
plt.ylabel("Score")
plt.title("37% Algorithm")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just read about this "Rule of 37%" so I hope I understood it correctly. I would implement something like that:

```
import random
def rule_of_37(candidates):
    # first I date random 37% of the candidates
    who_i_date = random.sample(list(candidates), int(len(candidates)*.37))
    print("I meet those 37% of the candidates", who_i_date)
    # then I calculate their average score
    average = sum(candidates[name] for name in who_i_date) / len(who_i_date)
    print("The average score was", average)
    # then I settle with the next person that has a score higher than the average (obviously I cannot re-date candidates)
    # hopefully there is still someone with an higher score than average...
    try:
        who_i_marry = next(name 
                           for name, score in candidates.items()
                           if name not in who_i_date
                           and score > average)
        print("I end up with", who_i_marry, "who has a score of", candidates[who_i_marry])
    except StopIteration:
        print("I end up all alone, there was nobody left with an higher score than", average, "...")

candidates={"Husain":85, "Chirag":94 ,"Asim":70,"Ankit":65 ,"Saiteja":65 ,"Absar":75 ,"Premraj":70 ,"Sagar":75 ,"Himani":75 ,"Parth":76 ,"Sumedha":70 ,"Revati":65 ,"Sageer":65 ,"Noorjahan":60 ,"Muzammil":65 ,"Shifa":56 , "Dipti":65 , "Dheeraj":70 }

rule_of_37(candidates)
```

Example execution (yours may vary since the first 37% candidates are picked at random):

> I meet those 37% of the candidates ['Dipti', 'Chirag', 'Revati', 'Sumedha', 'Dhe
>   eraj', 'Muzammil']
>
> The average score was 71.5
>
> I end up with Husain who has a score of 85

If you want to select the first candidates yourself instead of relying on random, you can simply replace who_i_date by your pre-selected list:

```
who_i_date = ['Husain', 'Chirag', 'Asim', 'Ankit', 'Saiteja', 'Absar']
```

But then the other 63% will be arbitrarily ordered so you may not always select the same one (unless you use Python 3.6+ which keeps dicts in order by default). If you want to date the remaining 63% in order, you have to iterate over a list of the candidates names rather than on the dict that maps names to scores.
I leave that up to you.

Comment: Can I iterate through "first" 37% of the candidates and then choose from the rest?

Comment: Yes you can. But first you need to understand that Python dicts have no notion of order, until python 3.6. That means that if you iterate over a dict, you have no guarantee to get the items in the same order that you inserted them (or in the same order you wrote the dict literal). So you should keep the "order" of the candidates in a separate list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lookup_num` along with `numpy` to simulate what candidates are "seen" within your function and then calculate the average score.  This function will randomly select `lookup_num` number of candidates from your dictionary (without replacement).  Using that subset the `average_score` is calculated.  The function will return the average score along with the dictionary of "seen" candidates to determine who was the best candidate from the 37% subset.

```
def lookup(candidates,lookup_num):
    # Randomly select lookup_num candidates without replacement
    seen_names = np.random.choice(candidates.keys(), size=lookup_num, replace=False)

    # Create a dictionary with the scores from the seen candidates.
    seen = {k: v for (k, v) in candidates.items() if k in seen_names}

    # Calculate the average score for the candidates who were seen
    average_score = sum([v for (k, v) in seen.items()]) / float(lookup_num)
   return seen, average_score
```

Your code calling `lookup` would become:

```
seen, average_score=lookup(candidates,lookup_num)
```

With the `average_score` and the list of candidates who were seen you can compare that to the rest of the candidates and apply your decision criteria for choosing the best candidate.

Comment: Our goal is to find the best candidate from the remaining candidates after 37%.